# NetworkingError AWS SES

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

I am sending emails using AWS SES. It was working fine, but recently I am getting Networking errors. Full stack track is as followling.

```
Error: write EPROTO 140495130142528:error:140770FC:SSL 
routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown 
protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:827:
at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:880:14)
message: 'write EPROTO 140495130142528:error:140770FC:SSL 
routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown 
protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:827:\n',
code: 'NetworkingError',
errno: 'EPROTO',
syscall: 'write',
region: 'us-east-1',
hostname: 'email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
retryable: true,
time: 2018-07-26T09:57:44.096Z
```

I am also getting following error.

```
TimeoutError: Connection timed out after 120000ms
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws- 
sdk/lib/http/node.js:83:34)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:208:7)
at TLSSocket.emitTimeout (_http_client.js:711:34)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)
at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:420:8)
at ontimeout (timers.js:482:11)
message: 'Connection timed out after 120000ms',
code: 'TimeoutError',
time: 2018-07-26T10:09:31.149Z,
region: 'us-east-1',
hostname: 'email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
retryable: true
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: @hrushilok Did you make changes in your network configuration before?